# Executing a Python function for the area of a circle

Tags: python

How can I write a Python function that does the following: Start with a running sum S = 0. Then, for N iterations:

1. Generate a random point in the unit square (0 < x < 1, 0 < y < 1).
2. If the random point satisfies x^2 + y^2 < 1, add one to S, otherwise add nothing
3. Find the running average of points (i.e., the sum S divided by the number of iterations so far)

What value does the running average approach?

Code (I gather that it is pi):

```
def area(N=1000):

    '''Approximate area of quarter-circle using a Monte Carlo Method'''
    S = 0
    av = np.zeros(N)
    for j in range(N):
            r = np.random.random(2)
            if r[0]**2 + r[1]**2 < 1:
                    S = S+1
            av[j] = float(S)/(j+1.)
    return av
```

However, I am unsure of how to execute this - I can enter this, and there are no bugs, but I am not sure of how I would obtain pi.

Comment: Your sum should approach $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Since the area of a circle with radius 1 is $\pi$ and you are only concerned with a quarter of that circle and you are randomly picking within an area of a 1x1 square (fully containing the quarter of the circle), the total number of times you pick some point inside of the quarter circle will be $\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}}{1} = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Have a look at the last values of the return `av`, they should be the best estimations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store all the values from the iterations.  This would get very memory costly if you ran for high values of N:

```
def area(N):
    '''Approximate area of quarter-circle using a Monte Carlo Method'''
    S = 0
    for j in range(N):
        r = np.random.random(2)
        if np.dot(r,r) < 1:
            S += 1
    return S/N
```

You can use this like this:

```
print(area(10**6))
```

yields approx: `0.784734`

Answer (score 0):

```
print ((S/N)*4)
```

For very large number of point (N > 10000)

```
area of the circle/area of the square = No:of points inside the circle/No:of points inside the square
```

that is,

```
(pi/4)/1 = s/N => pi = 4 * (s/N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy only solution:

```
def f(N):
    x = np.random.random(N)
    y = np.random.random(N)
    return (x*x + y*y < 1).mean()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I should have indicated that I had previously implemented: import numpy as np